# Is $\mathbb{Z}/n$ torsor on $X$ same as $n$-sheet covering of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space，is a $\mathbb{Z}/n$ torsor on $X$ the same as a $n$-sheet covering of $X$? Given a torsor, the total space is a $n$-sheet covering of $X$．Given a $n$-sheet covering, how do we find the action $\mathbb{Z}/n\times \widetilde{X}\to\widetilde{X}$?

Comment: Could you remind me what a torsor is here?

Comment: A torsor is a element of $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)$?

Comment: OK. That's the same thing as a regular covering space with deck transformation group $\Bbb Z/n$. There are three obstructions to an $n$-sheeted covering space being a $\Bbb Z/n$-torsor: 1) not all $n$-sheeted covering spaces are regular covering spaces; 2) Not all groups of order $n$ are $\Bbb Z/n$! 2) is resolved by considering only groups of prime order, say; and 1) is resolved by setting $n=2$: because then 2-sheeted covers are automatically regular. (The nontrivial deck transformation just swaps the two points in a fiber.)

Comment: ...what is the third obstruction?

Comment: "...Oops."${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's the same thing as a principal $\mathbb{Z}_n$-bundle on $X$, which is more structure than just an $n$-sheeted cover.